# How to write an std::floor function from scratch

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-manipulation

I would like to know how to write my own floor function to round a float down.

Is it possible to do this by setting the bits of a float that represent the numbers after the comma to 0?

If yes, then how can I access and modify those bits?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, doing anything with the bits of a non-integer type is not portable, or safe.  The easiest thing to do is cast it to an integer, and the compiler will do the entire function for you.   `int floor(float a) {return (int)a;}`

Comment: Is there any way around?
EDIT: btw, not really relevant, but I want to round a float down, not round off

Comment: Not portably, safely, or easily.  EDIT: round down to the nearest integer, or another place?

Comment: rounded down to a float with all the numbers after the comma set to 0, but it's not really relevant, I know how I would have to write it. I just want to know how to mess with bits in datatypes

Comment: Modified version: `float floor( float in ) { return int(in); }` Not much more complex than the one above...

Comment: @xcrypt You do realise that casting to `int` *is* rounding down? e.g. `(int)0.7 == 0`

Comment: To those suggesting solutions here: Casting to `int` is *rounding to zero*. That's truncation, not flooring. I.e. `floor(-3.1)` has to return `-4`, not `-3`.

Comment: You're all right. Sorry for the confusion I caused... for some reason I assumed that a cast to int rounded off instead of down. But still, like I mentioned earlier, it's not really relevant since I wanted to learn how to do this by bit twiddling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do bit twiddling on floating point numbers, but getting it right depends on knowing exactly what the floating point binary representation is.  For most machines these days its [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-754), which is reasonably straight-forward.  For example IEEE-754 32-bit floats have 1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, and 23 mantissa bits, so you can use shifts and masks to extract those fields and do things with them.  So doing trunc (round to integer towards 0) is pretty easy:

```
float trunc(float x) {
    union {
        float    f;
        uint32_t i;
    } val;
    val.f = x;
    int exponent = (val.i >> 23) & 0xff; // extract the exponent field;
    int fractional_bits = 127 + 23 - exponent;
    if (fractional_bits > 23) // abs(x) < 1.0
        return 0.0;
    if (fractional_bits > 0)
        val.i &= ~((1U << fractional_bits) - 1);
    return val.f;
}
```

First, we extract the exponent field, and use that to calculate how many bits after the
decimal point are present in the number.  If there are more than the size of the mantissa, then we just return 0.  Otherwise, if there's at least 1, we mask off (clear) that many low bits.  Pretty simple.  We're ignoring denormal, NaN, and infinity her, but that works out ok, as they have exponents of all 0s or all 1s, which means we end up converting denorms to 0 (they get caught in the first if, along with small normal numbers), and leaving NaN/Inf unchanged.

To do a floor, you'd also need to look at the sign, and rounds negative numbers 'up' towards negative infinity.

Note that this is almost certainly slower than using dedicated floating point intructions, so this sort of thing is really only useful if you need to use floating point numbers on hardware that has no native floating point support.  Or if you just want to play around and learn how these things work at a low level.

Comment: When you say 'most machines' does that mean it's not entirely portable? Could you specify?

Comment: Yes, this is not portable -- any given machine should document what floating point representation it uses, and, to my knowledge, all machines designed in the last 25 years use some flavor of IEEE-754, which was standardized in 1985, but there are probably some I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Mooing: you are correct -- typo on my initial submission, since corrected

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve what binary representation the system is using? So I could make this portable in one way or another?

Answer (score 3):

Define from scratch. And no, setting the bits of your floating point number representing the numbers after the comma to 0 will not work. If you look at [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), you will see that you basically have all your floating-point numbers in the form:

```
0.xyzxyzxyz 2^(abc)
```

So to implement flooring, you can get the xyzxyzxyz and shift left by abc+1 times. Drop the rest. I suggest you read up on the binary representation of a floating point number (link above), this should shed light on the solution I suggested.

NOTE: You also need to take care of the sign bit. And the mantissa of your number is off by 127.

Here is an example, Let's say you have the number pi: 3.14..., you want to get 3.

Pi is represented in binary as

```
0 10000000 10010010000111111011011
```

This translate to

```
sign = 0 ; e = 1 ; s = 110010010000111111011011
```

The above I get directly from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). Since e is 1. You will want to shift left s by 1 + 1 = 2, so you get 11 => 3.

Comment: You use a lot of terminology I don't understand... Could you give me some link to explain all this a bit? EDIT: I've never really messed with bits before. I know the logic operations like shift, but that's all.

Comment: @xcrypt shift isn't a logical operator. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

double round(double input, double roundto) {
    return int(input / roundto) * roundto;
}

int main() {
    double pi = 3.1415926353898;
    double almostpi = round(pi, 0.0001);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(14) << pi << '\n' << std::setprecision(14) << almostpi;
}
```

http://ideone.com/mdqFA
output:

> 3.1415926353898
>   3.1415

This will pretty much be faster than any bit twiddling you can come up with.  And it works on all computers (with floats) instead of just one type.

Comment: This is not much of a *floor*, it looks more like *round* to me

Comment: `to round a float down.`  `I want to round a float down, not round off` `rounded down to a float....`  The truncation answer was in the comments, he said that wasn't right.

Comment: This would round up. But I replied that I knew how to do it this way

Comment: @xcrypt: The answer(s) in the comments round down to the next lowest integer.  This answer rounds to the closest integer.  I don't understand what you want.  Did you want to round to the closest one-onehundredth?

Comment: @Mooing Duck Maybe I'm wrong then, does the default cast from float to integer round to the lowest integer instead of the closest?

What I want to achieve is something like floor(9.8) = 9.0

But still, doing the function like this is not what I wanted, I wanted to know how to do it from scratch, by manipulating bits (like in the first answer, that I sadly do not understand)

Comment: @xcrypt: yes, the default float->int conversion uses "truncation" which means it rounds down, always.  9.99999 -> 9.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to unsigned while returning as a double does what you are seeking, but under the hood. This simple piece of code works for any POSITIVE number.

```
#include <iostream>

double floor(const double& num) {
    return (unsigned long long) num; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been tested on [tio.run (Try It Online)](https://tio.run/##nVKxboMwEN35ikuqVJiEBDpCnA5VK1XK1LkLAQNW4RyBrZJG@XZqm6QpytR6st/dvXd@eqlfpGnfrzx4YzWrd6wBKYCh1JdW1EyWHAvgCLJk8Ip7JaFlqeQCJ@CtHOeOY1qpjK1bmXGxLDdOJfRAJtSuYlAfXiohGvc31hHQak9lggXTrLw1ggehGqj4hxaLYMTAi1I68JezY5BXIpFma8vbcqkSs/ISzM5HSzdaKRX7A@3WwWPn@WHUxbZDYcsLZJnmkfDFGtHSIL6ZRRoOYK7/aR6WbINeGMTo0TBYzOd2mFzbbItPMbaFCfXPUxoiP3/l@dC3Dq7YceSELc81zQjFlRYdQ75vha7gybmdb5hUDYJxYRCmVPsRdb4b@vZNSOR252vsnBzH@FInHF1ya@mZdN/optydPttAJYDqErHcBCOC6dmWNk1Q9822@XQB90jG47PlwzZ/R126JArJsMM/gqsDUolPE9@@/wY) and [onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/fork/yiH-PGt5o).  The function itself doesn't require any `#include` files, but to print out the answers, I have included `stdio.h` (in the [tio.run](https://tio.run/##nVKxboMwEN35ikuqVJiEBDpCnA5VK1XK1LkLAQNW4RyBrZJG@XZqm6QpytR6st/dvXd@eqlfpGnfrzx4YzWrd6wBKYCh1JdW1EyWHAvgCLJk8Ip7JaFlqeQCJ@CtHOeOY1qpjK1bmXGxLDdOJfRAJtSuYlAfXiohGvc31hHQak9lggXTrLw1ggehGqj4hxaLYMTAi1I68JezY5BXIpFma8vbcqkSs/ISzM5HSzdaKRX7A@3WwWPn@WHUxbZDYcsLZJnmkfDFGtHSIL6ZRRoOYK7/aR6WbINeGMTo0TBYzOd2mFzbbItPMbaFCfXPUxoiP3/l@dC3Dq7YceSELc81zQjFlRYdQ75vha7gybmdb5hUDYJxYRCmVPsRdb4b@vZNSOR252vsnBzH@FInHF1ya@mZdN/optydPttAJYDqErHcBCOC6dmWNk1Q9822@XQB90jG47PlwzZ/R126JArJsMM/gqsDUolPE9@@/wY) and [onlinegdb.com](https://onlinegdb.com/fork/yiH-PGt5o), not here).  Here it is:

```c
long double myFloor(long double x) /* Change this to your liking: long double might
                                             be float in your situation.  */
{
    long double xcopy=x<0?x*-1:x;
    unsigned int zeros=0;
    long double n=1;
    for(n=1;xcopy>n*10;n*=10,++zeros);
    for(xcopy-=n;zeros!=-1;xcopy-=n)
        if(xcopy<0)
        {
            xcopy+=n;
            n/=10;
            --zeros;
        }
    xcopy+=n;
    return x<0?(xcopy==0?x:x-(1-xcopy)):(x-xcopy);
}
```

This function works everywhere (pretty sure) because it just removes all of the non-decimal parts instead of trying to work with the parts of floats.

The floor of a floating point number is the biggest integer less than or equal to it.  Here are a some examples:

```
floor(5.7)  = 5
floor(3)    = 3
floor(9.9)  = 9
floor(7.0)  = 7
floor(-7.9) = -8
floor(-5.0) = -5
floor(-3.3) = -3
floor(0)    = 0
floor(-0.0) = -0
floor(-0)   = -0
```

Note: this is almost an exact copy from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64408800) which answered a question that was basically the same as this one.