# Write your own implementation of math's floor function, C

Tags: c, math, floor

I was thinking about the `floor` function available in `math.h`. It is very easy to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
 
int main(void)
{
  for (double a = 12.5; a < 13.4; a += 0.1)
    printf("floor of  %.1lf is  %.1lf\n", a, floor(a));
  return 0;
}
```

What if I would like to write my own implementation of it? Would it look simply like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double my_floor(double num)
{
    return (int)num;
}

int main(void)
{
    double a;

    for (a = 12.5; a < 13.4; a += 0.1)
        printf("floor of  %.1lf is  %.1lf\n", a, floor(a));

    printf("\n\n");

    for (a = 12.5; a < 13.4; a += 0.1)
        printf("floor of  %.1lf is  %.1lf\n", a, my_floor(a));

    return 0;
}
```

?

It seems it does not work with negative numbers (`my_floor`), but the second one seems to be fine (`my_floor_2`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double my_floor(double num)
{
    return (int)num;
}

double my_floor_2(double num)
{
    if(num < 0)
        return (int)num - 1;
    else
        return (int)num;
}

int main(void)
{
    double a1 = -12.5;

    printf("%lf\n", floor(a1));
    printf("%lf\n", my_floor(a1));
    printf("%lf\n", my_floor_2(a1));

    return 0;
}
```

program output:

```
-13.000000
-12.000000
-13.000000
```

Is one of them eventually correct or not?

Comment: `floor(x)` yields `the largest integer value less than or equal to x`.  If yours does that, it is correct right now.

Comment: You can try `my_floor_2(1e100)`, which will somehow tell you the difference,

Answer (score 7):

Both of your attempts have limitations:

- If the `double` value is outside the range of the `int` type, converting to `int` is implementation defined.
- If the `double` value is negative but integral, returning `(int)num - 1` is incorrect.

Here is an (almost) portable version that tries to handle all cases:

```
double my_floor_2(double num) {
    if (num >= LLONG_MAX || num <= LLONG_MIN || num != num) {
        /* handle large values, infinities and nan */
        return num;
    }
    long long n = (long long)num;
    double d = (double)n;
    if (d == num || num >= 0)
        return d;
    else
        return d - 1;
}
```

It should be correct if type `long long` has more value bits than type `double`, which is the case on most modern systems.

Comment: Corner: `num >= LLONG_MAX` has rounding mode issues as `LLONG_MAX` typically does not convert exactly to `double`.  Alternative: `(num >= (LLONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)`

Comment: Code could catch the NAN case with 2 tests: `if (!(num < (LLONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0 && num >= LLONG_MIN)) { ...`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the rounding issues in `num >= LLONG_MAX`, `num` are irrelevant in this particular case: if `long long` has more value bits than type `double`, if the test succeeds, `num` is a whole number, if it fails, `num` will convert to `long long` correctly. For the conversion to fail would require `num` to have a value larger than `LLONG_MAX`, which would necessarily be larger or equal to `(double)LLONG_MAX`.

Comment: Fair enough in this case usage.  My general concern stems from the implied `num >= (double) LLONG_MAX` and `(double) LLONG_MAX` becoming a value that differs from `LLONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't tackle it this way. The best way of writing your own implementation is to take the one from the C Standard Library on your platform. But note that might contain platform specific nuances so might not be portable.

The C Standard Library `floor` function is typically clever in that it doesn't work by taking a conversion to an integral type. If it did then you'd run the risk of `signed` integer overflow, the behaviour of which is undefined. (Note that the smallest possible range for an `int` is -32767 to +32767).

The precise implementation is also dependent on the floating point scheme used on your platform.

For a platform using IEEE754 floating point, and a `long long` type you *could* adopt this scheme:

1. If the magnitude of the number is greater than 2<sup>53</sup>, return it (as it's already integral).
2. Else, cast to a 64-bit type (`long long`), and return it back.

Comment: Casting to `long long` does not return the _floor_ when `num < 0`.

Comment: The approach also fails when `isnan(num)`.  Case 1. would benefit with refinement.

Comment: " The best way of writing your own implementation is to steal the one from the C Standard Library on your platform." <- That's only true if you're ok with a platform-specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In **C++** and 32 bit arithmetics it can be done for example like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IEEE 754 double MSW masks
const DWORD _f64_sig    =0x80000000;    // sign
const DWORD _f64_exp    =0x7FF00000;    // exponent
const DWORD _f64_exp_sig=0x40000000;    // exponent sign
const DWORD _f64_exp_bia=0x3FF00000;    // exponent bias
const DWORD _f64_exp_lsb=0x00100000;    // exponent LSB
const DWORD _f64_exp_pos=        20;    // exponent LSB bit position
const DWORD _f64_man    =0x000FFFFF;    // mantisa
const DWORD _f64_man_msb=0x00080000;    // mantisa MSB
const DWORD _f64_man_bits=       52;    // mantisa bits
// IEEE 754 single masks
const DWORD _f32_sig    =0x80000000;    // sign
const DWORD _f32_exp    =0x7F800000;    // exponent
const DWORD _f32_exp_sig=0x40000000;    // exponent sign
const DWORD _f32_exp_bia=0x3F800000;    // exponent bias
const DWORD _f32_exp_lsb=0x00800000;    // exponent LSB
const DWORD _f32_exp_pos=        23;    // exponent LSB bit position
const DWORD _f32_man    =0x007FFFFF;    // mantisa
const DWORD _f32_man_msb=0x00400000;    // mantisa MSB
const DWORD _f32_man_bits=       23;    // mantisa bits
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double f64_floor(double x)
    {
    const int h=1;      // may be platform dependent MSB/LSB order
    const int l=0;
    union _f64          // semi result
        {
        double f;       // 64bit floating point
        DWORD u[2];     // 2x32 bit uint
        } y;
    DWORD m,a;
    int sig,exp,sh;
    y.f=x;
    // extract sign
    sig =y.u[h]&_f64_sig;
    // extract exponent
    exp =((y.u[h]&_f64_exp)>>_f64_exp_pos)-(_f64_exp_bia>>_f64_exp_pos);
    // floor bit shift
    sh=_f64_man_bits-exp; a=0;
    if (exp<0)
        {
        a=y.u[l]|(y.u[h]&_f64_man);
        if (sig) return -1.0;
        return 0.0;
        }
    // LSW
    if (sh>0)
        {
        if (sh<32) m=(0xFFFFFFFF>>sh)<<sh; else m=0;
        a=y.u[l]&(m^0xFFFFFFFF); y.u[l]&=m;
        }
    // MSW
    sh-=32;
    if (sh>0)
        {
        if (sh<_f64_exp_pos) m=(0xFFFFFFFF>>sh)<<sh; else m=_f64_sig|_f64_exp;
        a|=y.u[h]&(m^0xFFFFFFFF); y.u[h]&=m;
        }
    if ((sig)&&(a)) y.f--;
    return y.f;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float f32_floor(float x)
    {
    union               // semi result
        {
        float f;        // 32bit floating point
        DWORD u;        // 32 bit uint
        } y;
    DWORD m,a;
    int sig,exp,sh;
    y.f=x;
    // extract sign
    sig =y.u&_f32_sig;
    // extract exponent
    exp =((y.u&_f32_exp)>>_f32_exp_pos)-(_f32_exp_bia>>_f32_exp_pos);
    // floor bit shift
    sh=_f32_man_bits-exp; a=0;
    if (exp<0)
        {
        a=y.u&_f32_man;
        if (sig) return -1.0;
        return 0.0;
        }
    if (sh>0)
        {
        if (sh<_f32_exp_pos) m=(0xFFFFFFFF>>sh)<<sh; else m=_f32_sig|_f32_exp;
        a|=y.u&(m^0xFFFFFFFF); y.u&=m;
        }
    if ((sig)&&(a)) y.f--;
    return y.f;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The point is to make mask that will clear out the decimal bits from mantissa and in case of negative input and non zero cleared bits decrement the result. To access individual bits you can convert your floating point value to integral representation with use of union (like in the example) or use pointers instead.

I tested this in simple **VCL** app like this:

```cpp
float f32;
double f64;
AnsiString txt="";
// 64 bit
txt+="[double]\r\n";
for (f64=-10.0;f64<=10.0;f64+=0.1)
 if (fabs(floor(f64)-f64_floor(f64))>1e-6)
    {
    txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%5.3lf %5.3lf %5.3lf\r\n",f64,floor(f64),f64_floor(f64));
    f64_floor(f64);
    }
for (f64=1;f64<=1e307;f64*=1.1)
    {
    if (fabs(floor( f64)-f64_floor( f64))>1e-6) { txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%lf lf lf\r\n", f64,floor( f64),f64_floor( f64));
    f64_floor( f64); }
    if (fabs(floor(-f64)-f64_floor(-f64))>1e-6) { txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%lf lf lf\r\n",-f64,floor(-f64),f64_floor(-f64));
    f64_floor(-f64); }
    }
// 32 bit
txt+="[float]\r\n";
for (f32=-10.0;f32<=10.0;f32+=0.1)
 if (fabs(floor(f32)-f32_floor(f32))>1e-6)
    {
    txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%5.3lf %5.3lf %5.3lf\r\n",f32,floor(f32),f32_floor(f32));
    f32_floor(f32);
    }
for (f32=1;f32<=1e37;f32*=1.1)
    {
    if (fabs(floor( f32)-f32_floor( f32))>1e-6) { txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%lf lf lf\r\n", f32,floor( f32),f32_floor( f32));
    f32_floor( f32); }
    if (fabs(floor(-f32)-f32_floor(-f32))>1e-6) { txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%lf lf lf\r\n",-f32,floor(-f32),f32_floor(-f32));
    f32_floor(-f32); }
    }
mm_log->Lines->Add(txt);
```

with no difference result (so in all tested cases it matches `math.h` `floor()` values. If you want to give this a shot outside **VCL** then just change `AnsiString` to any string type you got at hand and change the output from `TMemo::mm_log` to anything you got (like console `cout` or whatever)

The double calling of `fxx_floor()` in case of difference is for debuging purposes (you can place a breakpoint and step in the error case directly).

**[Notes]**

Beware the order of words (**MSW,LSW**) is platform dependent so you should adjust the `h,l` constants accordingly. This code is not optimized so it is easily understandable so do not expect it will be fast.

Answer (score 0):

When the precision of the floating point type is small enough as compared to a wide integer type, cast to that integer type when the floating point value is in the integer range.

Review the function for values outside the `intmax_t` range, NAN, infinity and -0.0 and adjust as desired.

```c
#if DBL_MANT_DIG >= 64
#error TBD code
#endif
#include <inttypes.h>

// INTMAX_MAX is not exact as a double, yet INTMAX_MAX + 1 is an exact double
#define INTMAX_MAX_P1 ((INTMAX_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)

double my_floor(double x) {
  if (x >= 0.0) {
    if (x < INTMAX_MAX_P1) {
      return (double)(intmax_t)x;
    }
    return x;
  } else if (x < 0.0) {
    if (x >= INTMAX_MIN) {
      intmax_t ix = (intmax_t) x; 
      return (ix == x) ? x : (double)(ix-1);
    }
    return x;
  }
  return x; // NAN
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVPBjtNADD1nvuJtEWzTbjeJgEvTLAfESkhw4cxlmjjtiGQmykzYFrTfXjyTRGy5IlWq/Ww/P3uccnMoy8slWeEbtdTuqYczIO3YsKYld1T6AKXhjoTbz7ob3C0slU4ZjT015ukGq0QkCZ4ImqiCtGiH8gjbyZK81xlr1b4h4c4dVVSjMUxZmYExNLI/kHWPjZEuF@Kli/bM/6ZfXoGnWPwW0TVUmu6MAssTdkhjfPDWCpssxhanXESDtuqgWZvSDr@oN5az0/wfGs1gxqCIeJqPZuDcSh2UszxnbXoKK6ioVK1sRMQIlmPJJODB@ytkaZwz14oj6R3W69AvFlE0U3@VP2gqqU3DG0SKXTEhO2QT9@hvCuh80nxT8ExzNx@IwauIVD0nh@k9FI3@2hd7VyPxcoK92QQ2bz8L/7vKDQofR1nWSV3JvkLtn4G3cJQ/lenF2DF0Y5Ke3NDrWUJRjC9w4tVzznpWiyxmdmos/S05MRzCuXgW4pXSZTNUhJ11lTL3xwch/Hu1UullGOv6tZiu6zmhXi4@hXOV0MN8wEHxFgvf1JZSc9LrL/XiDm90/KKQse@a0SswHB1VW8zR@Q517NMm8WkQ/Z/fzeWSvb1/9/4P). Try this as your function:

```c
// we need as much space as possible
typedef long double largestFloat;

largestFloat myFloor(largestFloat x)
{
    largestFloat xcopy = (x < 0) ? (x * -1) : x;
    unsigned int zeros = 0;
    largestFloat n = 1;
    
    // Count digits before the decimal
    for (n = 1; xcopy > (n * 10); n *= 10, ++zeros)
        ;
    
    // Make xcopy follow 0 <= xcopy < 1
    for (xcopy -= n; zeros != -1; xcopy -= n) {
        if (xcopy < 0) {
            xcopy += n;
            n /= 10;
            --zeros;
        }
    }
    xcopy += n;
    
    // Follow standard floor behavior
    if (x < 0)
        return (xcopy == 0) ? x : (x + xcopy - 1);
    else
        return x - xcopy;
}
```

This is an explanation of the code.

1. Create `xcopy` (absolute value of `x`)
2. Use the first `for` loop to figure out the number of digits before the decimal point.
3. Use that number to continually decrease `xcopy` until it satisfies `0 <= xcopy < 1`
4. Based on whether `x` was originally positive or negative, either return `x - xcopy` or `x - (1 - xcopy)`.